# Why won't the Note Board SharePoint 2013 web part work?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a dashboard via SharePoint and I would like to create a section beneath a displayed document where users can type and submit a description of what is going on in the document above. I don't want the users to be able to edit the site page in order to add text to the page so I believe the best solution would be the creation of a web part where a user can create and submit their desired description. The only web parts that I've come across to do something like this are the Note Board web part and the Microfeed web part. The Microfeed part seems too much like a social media page. My problem is I would like to try the Note Board web part but whenever I insert it on the page it never displays an area to type in, just the title "Note Board".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this problem came up because of the way my account is related to this particular SharePoint site that I am editing. My account doesn't have a profile attached to it essentially and the way that these notes are shared and stored directly relates to having one of these profiles. The Note Board Web Part turned out to be working perfectly fine my account is just not capable of posting within it. (I figured I'd answer incase anyone else comes up with this problem.)

Comment: If all the accounts you wish to have view this have full profiles attached to them then the Note Board Web Part fits your needs. Otherwise I would suggest using the Announcement app and then just display the contents of the desired set of announcements on the page where you want them.